# How is this function changing my readonly variable?

Tags: c#, xmpp

I am using jabber.net in C# and there is a quirk that has confused me so hopefully someone can explain how it is doing it. I am still quite new to C# from a C++ background so it may be a misunderstanding there

I am creating a readonly JID to hold a room that I need to enter:

```
private readonly JID messagingRoomJID;

public MyClass
{
   // Reads from database but for purpose of this question
   messagingRoomJID = new JID("user@myserver");
}
```

Later I want to join a room which is where I get the thing I am confused by

```
conferenceManager = new ConferenceManager();
conferenceManager.Stream = xmppClient;

// Before entering this room messagingRoomJID.Resource == null
theRoom = conferenceManager.GetRoom(messagingRoomJID);
// But now messagingRoomJID.Resource contains my username
```

But how is Resource being changed? The variable is readonly but also shouldn't it be passed by const reference, so how is it being updated anyway?

It looks like I can do it by this but I am not sure it is sensible:

```
theRoom = conferenceManager.GetRoom(new JID(messagingRoomJID));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not changing the value of your variable. The value of your variable is just a reference. That reference is staying the same as it was before.

What's changing is the data within the object that the reference refers to. The `readonly` modifier *only* applies to your variable - it doesn't say anything about the mutability of the object itself.

It's very important to distinguish between references and objects - see [my article on the topic](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more information.

Comment: Wow, lots of fast responses. I understand now what is happening. I had thought it worked more like const references in C++ but of course that is not the case which I kind of think is unfortunate but I am sure there are many good reasons why this is the case. So is it the case that in the normal instance when you pass an object to a function you have no guarantee that it is untouched by their code?

Comment: @Firedragon: You don't pass an object. You pass a reference, by value (assuming it's a reference type, and it's not a ref/out parameter). And yes, anything can mutate the object, if it's a mutable type. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html for more about parameter passing. Basically, don't assume that C# is like C++ - it's not! :)

Comment: It might not sound like it but that's kind of what I meant. Just not the best at explaining myself :-) I guess it's similar to C++ as references are passed by value also but dissimilar in that there isn't the same const-correctness

Answer (score 3):

Because it is changing a *property* of your `readonly` variable, whereas only the root element is readonly per se.

For instance,

```
private readonly int MyReadOnlyVariable;
private readonly ComplexType MyReadOnlyComplexType;

public MyClass()
{
    MyReadOnlyVariable = 2;            //valid
    MyReadOnlyComplexType = something; //valid
}

public void NotAConstructor()
{
    MyReadOnlyVariable = 2;                          //invalid
    MyReadOnlyComplexType = somethingElse;           //invalid
    MyReadOnlyComplexType.Something = somethingElse; //valid
}
```

So, we can change *it* once, in the constructor; but in the case of a complex type containing properties, exposed fields and such and so, we *can* alter those ever after. This is why (for a common example) having a `readonly` array is generally a bad idea, or at least conceivable that it often isn't what is intended - since the elements of the array can be changed.

Comment: It's actually the reference to the instance that's readonly, not the instance itself, and a property of the *instance* that the variable is referring to, not of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

So, I consider Jon Skeet's answer as correct. 
As an example, your class variable **messagingRoomJID** is readonly and a reference, so you can't assign it to a new value, but you can certainly change the values of all its properties because the property "Resource" is not readonly.

The GetRoom() method call doesnt change the messagingRoomJID variable reference in memory, it only changes the value of one of its properties which is allowed.

Comment: This could have well been a comment to Jon's answer ! !

Comment: I agree, I didnt have the commenting privilege that time, I have it now and heres my first comment..Thanks for the privilige..!!

Answer (score 1):

`readonly` means that reference to the instance will not be changed. But you can change any field of this object. When is passed to method `GetRoom`, its passed by reference. So `GetRoom` can change any object's field.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) , readonly fields can be initialized during declaration or by using a constructor.

> A readonly field can be initialized either at the declaration or in a constructor. Therefore, readonly fields can have different values depending on the constructor used.

However, as in your code you are not changing either during the initialization or using a constructor but still the property `Resource` contains the value.

As pointed out by Jon Skeet, I would attempt to add to it, the value of a reference type variable is either `null` or a `memorry address`.

So ,when you declare :

```
private readonly JID messagingRoomJID;
```

At that time `messagingRoomJID` is readonly but there are few property present at that memory location , in this case `Resource`  can be changed to another value.